# Show a scheme is integral if and only if it is irreducible and reduced.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I'm trying to solve Exercise 5.2.F from Vakil's notes:

> Show a scheme $X$ is integral if and only if it is irreducible and reduced.

Where we say $X$ is reduced (integral) if $\mathscr O_X(U)$ is reduced (an integral domain) for all open subsets $U$ of $X$.

Clearly, if $X$ is integral, then each $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$ is a domain, hence reduced, so $X$ is reduced. I'm not sure how to see that $X$ is irreducible. It's obvious for an affine scheme, since if $\mathscr{O}_X(X)=:A$ is a domain then $\text{Spec } A$ is irreducible. Am I able to use this to tackle the general case? Like if $X=\cup_i U_i$ with each $U_i$ affine open, does each $U_i$ being irreducible imply that $X$ is irreducible? This doesn't seem like the right way to approach it.

I'm not sure, I just feel stuck. Any hints would be greatly appreciated (I'd prefer that over someone just giving me the answer).

Comment: Do you want hints for the reverse direction as well?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yeah that'd be helpful. I couldn't even find a starting point for that direction..

Comment: If $X = \cup U_i$ with $U_i$ affine open and irreducible, then $X$ is irreducible IF you assume it's connected. in general, it is not

Comment: Be careful here. The affine scheme $\text{Spec }\mathbb{R}[x,y]/V(xy)$ is connected but not irreducible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint for the forward direction: If $X$ is not irreducible, that means there are two disjoint nonempty open subsets $U,V\subset X$.  Consider $\mathscr{O}_X(U\cup V)$.

Hint for the reverse direction: If $X$ is irreducible and reduced, so is any open subscheme of $X$, so every nonempty affine open subscheme of $X$ is Spec of a domain.  To show $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$ is a domain for arbitrary $U$, you can show that the restriction $\mathscr{O}_X(U)\to\mathscr{O}_X(V)$ is injective for any nonempty affine open subset $V\subseteq U$.

A stronger hint for the reverse direction is hidden below:

> To show the restriction $\mathscr{O}_X(U)\to\mathscr{O}_X(V)$ is injective, suppose $f$ is in its kernel.  Then $f$ vanishes on $V$.  To show $f$ vanishes on $U$, it suffices to show $f$ vanishes on $W$ for every other affine open $W\subseteq U$.  Now use the fact that $W$ is Spec of a domain and $f$ vanishes on $V\cap W$.

Comment: Why does showing that the restriction is injective imply that $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ is a domain?

Comment: A subring of a domain is a domain.

Comment: Note that by this point in Vakil's notes we have not shown that $\operatorname{Spec}{A}$ irreducible and reduced implies that $A$ is a domain (only the reverse implication), so some argumentation will be required to fill in this step

Comment: @EricWofsey Can you give a further hint to considering $\mathcal O_X(U \cup V)$. I'm considering this but don't see where to go next.

Comment: @user46372819: What does the sheaf condition tell you about $\mathcal{O}_X(U\cup V)$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Since $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, a cover for $U \cup V$ is $\{U, V\}$. For this cover, the sheaf condition tells us two things: i.) if $f, g \in \mathcal O (U \cup V)$ are two sections such that $f|_U = g|_U$ and $f|_V = g|_V$, then $f=g$; ii.) since $U \cap V= \varnothing$, then for any $s_U \in \mathcal O(U)$ and any $s_V \in \mathcal O(V)$, there exists $s \in \mathcal O(U \cup V)$ such that $s|_U = s_U$ and $s|_V = s_V$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ok, I actually see now how this will give an isomorphism $\mathcal O(U \cup V) \to \mathcal O(U) \times \mathcal O(V)$. However, how do we know both $\mathcal O(U)$ and $\mathcal O(V)$ are nonzero?

Comment: @user46372819: $U$ and $V$ are nonempty.

Comment: @EricWofsey Why does that guarantee $\mathcal O(U) \ne 0$ or $\mathcal O(V) \ne 0$?

Comment: Pick any nonempty affine open subset $U'\subseteq U$ and consider the restriction map $\mathcal{O}(U)\to\mathcal{O}(U')$.

Answer (score 8):

If there were any disjoint open subsets $U,V$ then by the sheaf axioms $$\mathcal{O}_X(U \cup V) \cong \mathcal{O}_X(U) \times \mathcal{O}_X(V)$$ via restrictions $s \mapsto (s|_U, s|_V)$. This product has zero divisors of the form $(0,t)$ and $(t,0)$ unless one of $U$ and $V$ is empty. Contradiction since $\mathcal{O}_X(U \cup V)$ is integral.

This appears as Proposition 3.27 in Görtz, Wedhorn's Algebraic Geometry (which is a great reference for the basics of schemes).

Comment: Could you teach me what is the axiom of sheaf you used here?

Answer (score 1):

In Vakil's note there is a possible hint for the reverse direction by using exercise 4.3.G

> exercise 4.3.G:
>   (a) If f is a function on a locally ringed space X, show that the subset of X where f vanishes is closed.
>   (b) Show that if f is a function on a locally ringed space that vanishes nowhere,
>   then f is invertible.

So if fg=0, you can find two closed set covering the scheme by (a). To prove the closed set is neither empty or X, you can use (b) and the fact that X is reduced.