# Does Hartshorne assume curves are irreducible when proving that pullback along a finite morphism of nonsingular curves preserves linear equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

The question is how it can be proved the statement in the title:

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a finite morphism of nonsingular curves.

Then the pullback morphism $f^*:\operatorname{Div} Y \to \operatorname{Div} X$ preserves linear equivalence.

I have found this very same topic answered here:

[Let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite morphism of nonsingular curves. Then $f^*: \operatorname{Div} Y \to \operatorname{Div} X$ preserves linear equivalence.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227802/let-f-x-to-y-be-a-finite-morphism-of-nonsingular-curves-then-f-operato)

In my opinion the answer linked above (and consequently the proof) is correct as long as one assumes that at least the curve $Y$ is irreducibile. So my doubt is: is it so obvious that we are dealing with irreducibile curves at the point that the book doesn't even specify it?  In such case why?
Or am I wrong about the fact that the proof assumes the irreducibility of   ? In such case I am not able to justify this part of the proof:

"[...] On the other hand, for each $Q_i$
we can find an open set of
on which $g=u\cdot g_i^{v_{Q_i(g)}}$ [...] "

since I cannot understand why it must exist an open neighborhood in which both $g$ and $g_i$ are regular.

I hope my doubt is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax for all math in your post - I noticed you had used it for some of the math, but not all of it, so I took the liberty of fixing it this time. I also adjusted your title to try and get a little closer to what you were asking about (your confusion about whether irreducibility was assumed). Hopefully the title change is better in your eyes - feel free to keep improving it if you like :)

Comment: Thanks you! @KReiser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we are dealing with irreducible curves at that point in the book. From just before remark II.4.10.1 (page 105 in my copy):

> **Definition.** An *abstract variety* is an integral separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field $k$. If it is proper over $k$, we will say it is *complete*.
>
> **Remark 4.10.1.** From now on we will use the word "variety" to mean "abstract variety" in the sense just defined. We will identify the varieties of chapter I with their associated schemes, and refer to them as quasi-projective varieties. We will use the words "curve", "surface", "three-fold", etc., to mean an abstract variety of dimension 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, unfortunately I'm still missing the point. I was aware of the fact that we were dealing with abstract varieties, and now I assume that this implies that they are irreducibile. I don't understand why.

Comment: @ChiaraM an integral scheme is irreducible and reduced (see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082845/show-a-scheme-is-integral-if-and-only-if-it-is-irreducible-and-reduced)). Integral is a part of the definition of an abstract variety.

Comment: really, really thank you, now it is clear.

Comment: @ChiaraM you're welcome. If this resolves your question, you may wish to consider [accepting this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time._) by clicking the checkmark.